# No sound from monitor speakers with HDMI

Tags: windows-10, audio, display, hdmi, speakers

I have two [Acer G276HL](https://www.google.com/search?q=Acer%20G276HL&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS705US705&oq=Acer%20G276HL&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j35i39l2j0l2.3343j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) monitors. I only have one connected to my system now. I am running it through an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 video card.

A while ago, I was able to get sound from the monitor speakers. For some reason, this has ceased to be the case.

I have attempted everything I can think of to get this to work.

Made sure that the default playback device was set to the monitor:
[image]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling through the device manager:
[image]

I've run a system scan from the command line. I've run a registry cleaning. I've noticed that there is some event saying that the device was "Not Migrated" in the device manager: [image]

I am sure that my monitors have functioning speakers. I've done everything that I can to resolve this problem but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I have a tv hooked to hdmi through my computer that I sometimes use. In order to have my sound run through the HDMI I have to open my sound sttings and select my output device to be (SHARP TV). This may be the case, as you stated you did this. Sometimes I have the audio port plugged into my stereo and the computer gets upset and will only use the audio port and not the HDMI. If possible only use the HDMI wires for your sound. Depending on your Os there are a few places the setting may not be the same as in your device properties, there are also some variables, like is your monitor controlling the speakers? It's hard to tell without knowing all the details. My thought would be to ensure the speakers are on and working then the same with your computers sound then check the device and system settings as well as your apps to make sure all the sound is going through your hdmi port. Your Nvidia drivers may play a part as well depending on what software you have installed.

Good luck.